# What is the difference/benifit of golden cards?

Tags: hearthstone

I don't see any difference in these cards in stats or effect.
Besides the fact that they are golden, do they serve any purpose?

I understand that with a real card game a golden one would be worth more to trade or sell, but as far as i know, this game has no trading option(s).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Hearthstone - Golden Cards](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Golden_card)

> Golden cards are special, rarer versions of cards. Each card exists in both a regular and a golden form.
>   The difference between a card's normal version and its golden version is purely aesthetic - all golden cards feature a golden frame, and each has a unique animation.
>
> There is no difference in gameplay or behaviour on the battlefield, and golden cards do not allow you to circumvent the 2-per-deck (1-per-deck for legendaries) card restriction.
>
> Golden cards are commonly compared with "foil" cards of other Trading Card Games, and are far harder and more costly to obtain than their regular versions. Golden cards are intended to allow players to show off their card-collecting achievements.

While they may contain no tactical advantage than regular cards, the main and most important difference is that they will grant more dust during disenchanting; which varies by rarity

[Hearthstone - Crafting](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crafting)

[image]

As @Sconibulus mentioned, you have a chance to obtaining a *Gold Coin* if your deck consists entirely of gold cards.

[Hearthstone - The Coin](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Coin)

> If a player's deck is composed entirely of golden cards, they will
>       be granted a golden version of The Coin when going second.

Another cool aspect, which is purely cosmetic, is that if you play a gold card that replaces or upgrades your Hero Power, you will obtain a gold hero power

> **Replacing Hero Powers** (*cited from Gold Card link*)
>
> - Cards which replace a Hero Power with another one (such as Lord
>     Jaraxxus, Sir Finley Mrrgglton or Shadowform) will only grant golden
>     Hero Powers if the card is golden. For example, playing a regular Sir
>     Finley Mrrgglton with a golden Hero Power will replace it with a
>     regular Hero Power; playing a regular Shadowform after playing a
>     golden Shadowform will replace the golden Mind Spike with a regular
>     Mind Shatter.
> - The one exception is Justicar Trueheart, which will produce a golden Hero Power if either the card or the Hero Power is golden.
>     This may be because the card conceptually "upgrades" the Hero Power.

Comment: @downvoter. Can you elaborate so that I may expand my answer?

Comment: You're missing the one actual difference/benefit of Golden cards besides the fact that they are golden, which is the fact that they can be disenchanted for double the dust value of regular cards.

Comment: @hammythepig Ah ha, I didn't catch that. I updated my answer. The disenchanting is not necessarily *doubled*, but varies by rarity

Comment: Much better answer :)

Comment: Specifically other than commons, you get as much dust as it takes to craft a non-golder card of that rarity so you can effectively exchange it within the same rarity for anything you want.

Answer (score 8):

In terms of game mechanics they give more dust when you convert them, double that of their non-gold counterparts.

Other than that, they're just there to look cool. (the pictures also have slight movement)

Comment: +1 for the fact that you mentioned the only real difference, double the dust. the other answer doesn't have that.

Comment: Since when is it double? It always used to be the same price a regular card of that rarity costs to craft, which is a lot more than twice as much as you get from a normal card disenchant.

Answer (score 4):

Golden Cards have several benefits, none of them tactile save two.

- **All cards may be dis-enchanted for dust**, this dust can be used to 'craft' specific cards you want, therefore circumventing the 'random' nature of the packs you open. **Golden Cards grant twice as much dust as their normal counterparts.** This is the first tactile benefit.
- Golden cards count as an additional card not an upgrade to an existing one, so if you have one Normal Card and one Golden Card you can put both in your deck to meet the 2 card maximum. This is the second tactile benefit.
- Golden Cards have the visual benefit of having animated pictures that often are more interesting to look at than normal ones and flaunt some flair for you as you play. This obviously has no real impact on the game itself.
- Golden Cards that have abilities that create other cards will share their golden animated picture benefit to their produced offspring. Once again this is just for show.
- If a player's deck is entirely composed of Golden Cards and they start the game going second, they will receive a Golden Coin instead of a Normal Coin. *Thanks @Sconibulus for this contribution!*

Comment: Also, as an extra super bonus, if your deck consists entirely of gold cards, you have a 50% chance of starting the game with a 'gold coin', otherwise attainable only through roguish minions.